# How can I calculate definite integral of chi-squared pdf with one degree of freedom

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} x^{\frac{1}{2}-1} e^{-x / 2} d x
$$

I need a calculating process of the above definite integral.

Comment: Looks for gamma function/gamma integral.

Comment: Everything works... Try the change of variable $x=t^2$ and check the normal PDF.